# setting the time delta format in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet form response data where column B is a time duration value. But it shows time in AM or PM. I tried different app script  but still unable to get the value a time Delta( difference) format 
The form response data itself gives time in AM or PM. Help me in this matter.
This is my latest code.

```
function timeFormat() {
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet4').getRange('B1:B');
    cell.setNumberFormat('hh:mm');
  }
```

Comment: Are the values in column B times or durations? Durations can't have AM or PM, which is why I'm confused. Also, do you need to set this value via script or could you  just set it in the Sheets menu Format > Number > Duration ?

Comment: With form response sheet, you can't apply custom formatting to the entire range. As soon as the new response is submitted, the format of the new rows will override the custom format you set previously. You can either 1) use onFormSubmit() trigger to re-apply the custom format every time the response is submitted or 2) create a separate sheet with custom formatting for storing responses from the form sheet . If your values range is, say , A:D you can automatically copy all new form responses to the new sheet  
 with this formula = form_sheet_name!A:D

Comment: @Diego what you said is correct durations cannot have AM or PM But in my sheet it is shown as AM or PM I want a script to correct it

Comment: @AntonDementiev Actually I move those rows which I need to another sheet , I am facing the above error in the new sheet. In my new sheet the duration is in AM or PM I want it in his:mm for further manipulation

Comment: @KumaraGuru I'm still confused as to why you need this as a script. Why not just set the formatting through the Sheets UI? I ask because I think this may affect the appropriate solution to your issue.

Comment: Isn't Cooper's script helpful to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your issue basically with the AM / PM part popping up when you click into the cells formatted as 'hh:mm'? You can fix that by applying the duration format for hours to the entire range (e.g. B2:B)

GAS:

```
range.setNumberFormat('[hh]:mm');
```

Or manually under Format -> Number -> More Formats -> Custom number format (a lot easier)

[image]

And here's how the end result looks like. Note that you get the 'AM/PM' part popping up when you click into cells formatted as 'hh:mm' but not with the ones formatted as [hh]:mm:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use this function as a cell function and then format the cells as a duration and you will get hours:minutes:seconds.

```
function days(Start,End) {
  if(Start && End)
  {
    var second=1000;
    var minute=60*second;
    var hour=minute*60;
    var day=hour*24;
    var t1=new Date(Start).valueOf();
    var t2=new Date(End).valueOf();
    var d=t2-t1;
    return d/day;
  }
  else
  {
    return 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}
```

This essentially returns the date number in the form that the spreadsheet understands as days and fraction of days.

Comment: What is this start and end variable denote

Comment: They could be dates or they could be strings that the date constructor recognizes